# serial redirect from 12.04 server usb installer

Tags: boot, server, usb, live-usb, software-installation

I have downloaded 12.04.4 LTS server iso (64 bit) and used netbootin to create a bootable usb thumb drive for the purpose of installing ubuntu server on a dell r620.  I have serial console connected and working for the host (I can see bios post, etc).  I can boot from the usb thumb drive and get to the unetbootin menu where I select install ubuntu server.  Once I select that option (or any of the others - expert install etc), I don't see any output on my remote console connection.  I do however see output on my direct connected monitor/keyboard (crash cart).  It is my assumption that the serial redirect setup is not done on the files on the thumb drive version of OS.

My ultimate goal is to be able to get hw to a datacenter, have it racked and cabled, have serial connection setup, have one of these usb thumb drives attached and from there I can do the install etc.  This is sort of a one off and I don't want to install via our usual pxe/kickstart method.

Can someone point me to a guide to "unpack" the iso files, add the serial redirection bits I need and then "repack" into an iso so I can then burn the iso to the thumb drive (using unetbootin)?  Or is there a different/better way?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but this might be useful to others...

I've been attempting something similar, and ended up using the net-based installer, rather than the full iso. This is trivial to modify for later releases, just change the two URLs...

Basically, grab a USB thumb drive with a single (bootable) FAT partition, then prepare it on a working ubuntu box:

```
apt-get install syslinux
syslinux /dev/disk/by-id/usb-...-part1
mount /dev/disk/by-id/usb-....-part1 /mnt
cd /mnt
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
cat <<EOT > syslinux.cfg
CONSOLE 0
SERIAL 0 115200 0
default linux
append initrd=initrd.gz console=ttyS0,115200n8
EOT
umount /mnt
```

Taken from:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/i386/ch04s03.html#usb-copy-flexible
- http://www.pcengines.info/forums/?page=post&id=E25612E9-84F0-4DCF-A876-1E92FD1D065C